# Can I create a self updating module in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, module

So I have a column with data that need to be simplified.

```
ColumnA      ColumnB  

Cyan          Blue  
Navy          Blue  
Forest        Green
```

I want to write a module that would ask me what to do about cyan when it first encounters it and I have to input blue. But for all the instances that cyan is encountered after this, the corresponding column B needs to be blue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub SIMPLIFY()
    RECORD_COUNT = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To RECORD_COUNT
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Columns("A"), Range("A" & i)) > 0 Then
            RECORD_ROW = WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("A" & i), Columns("A"), 0)
            If Cells(RECORD_ROW, 2) <> Empty Then
                Cells(i, 2) = Cells(RECORD_ROW, 2)
            Else
                Cells(i, 2) = InputBox("Input Color for " & Cells(i, 1))
            End If
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Copy above code to worksheet VBA.
The code waits for any changes in column "A" and checks for previous data.
It inputs color automatically if it exists, or it asks for color when it's new.

Comment: I didn't get how to use this code. [link](http://superuser.com/questions/309524/how-do-i-use-a-private-sub-in-excel) I used refrenced to this question to figure out how to use private subs but still I cant.

Comment: You can right click on the Worksheet Tab. Then click on "View Code". It will lead you to where you can paste above code. Go back to Worksheet you selected. Then you can try inputting data on Worksheet column "A". You will see how it works.Let me know if you have further questions

Comment: oh wow. thanks for the help I did get your code to work. but its not quite what I wanted. Column A is already filled with data. I don't have to manually input it.

Comment: I don't think I understood the question right. I have a questions. Do you want it to search for the data and ask when it's not previously entered? And what will triggers the code?

Comment: column A has pre filled data. I wanted a code that looks up the item in  row 1 in column A. asks me to input a colour for it. then adds that colour to column B row 1.
if that same item again appears in column A row 2, add the same colour to row B row 2. if not, then ask for a the colour again. 

very similar to the code you posted. but I have no idea how to edit it.

Comment: What will trigger the code? In other words when you do "Something" the code will run. What will "Something" be? For my previous code "Something" will be when you change data on column "A"

Comment: I want to be able to trigger a code. like a module.

Comment: I edited my post. See if the post meets your request.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. 

and yes!! that's exactly what I wanted. thanks for being patient with me! you're one of the nicest guys I met here!!!! 

excellent answer

Comment: can this be extended? if there are multiple files that have data that needs to be colour coded can I "save" the results that I typed in first file and if that word appears again in another file it be auto filled?

Comment: If you are talking about different workbook, then It will not work. Either you have to copy the code and run macro on each workbooks or change "Range" to "Workbooks(WorkbookName).Sheets(SheetName).Range"